# Broadleaf Commerce cannot startup due to MergePersistenceUnitManager exception

Tags: spring, tomcat6, broadleaf-commerce

I have had a live instance running for a while now on version 3.1.3-GA. I attempted to upgrade to 3.1.10-GA and everything was good on dev. When I deployed to live the application failed to initialize properly with the same error as below. I have rolled everything back to 3.1.3-GA and there have been no other changes but I still can't get the system to restart. The log has the following for each restart - the exception is about 30 lines in.

I am running tomcat 6.0.39

```
     [ERROR] 16:09:00 MergePersistenceUnitManager - The classes
     [org.broadleafcommerce.common.currency.domain.BroadleafCurrencyImpl, org.broadleafcommerce.common.locale.domain.LocaleImpl, org.broadleafcommerce.common.currency.domain.BroadleafCurrencyImpl]
     are managed classes within the MergePersistenceUnitManager
     but were not detected as being transformed by the EntityMarkerClassTransformer. These
     classes are likely loaded earlier in the application startup lifecyle by the servlet
     container. Verify that an empty <absolute-ordering /> element is contained in your
     web.xml to disable scanning for ServletContainerInitializer classes by your servlet
     container which can trigger early class loading. If the problem persists, ensure that
     there are no bean references to your entity class anywhere else in your Spring applicationContext
     and consult the documentation for your servlet container to determine if classes are loaded
     prior to the Spring context initialization.
     [ WARN] 16:09:00 MergeXmlWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
     org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in resource loaded from byte array: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'blPersistenceUnitManager' while setting bean property 'persistenceUnitManager'; nested e$
     [org.broadleafcommerce.common.currency.domain.BroadleafCurrencyImpl, org.broadleafcommerce.common.locale.domain.LocaleImpl, org.broadleafcommerce.common.currency.domain.BroadleafCurrencyImpl]
     are managed classes within the MergePersistenceUnitManager
     but were not detected as being transformed by the EntityMarkerClassTransformer. These
     classes are likely loaded earlier in the application startup lifecyle by the servlet
     container. Verify that an empty <absolute-ordering /> element is contained in your
     web.xml to disable scanning for ServletContainerInitializer classes by your servlet
     container which can trigger early class loading. If the problem persists, ensure that
     there are no bean references to your entity class anywhere else in your Spring applicationContext
     and consult the documentation for your servlet container to determine if classes are loaded
     prior to the Spring context initialization.

             at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:334)
             at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
             at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1419)
             at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
             at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
             at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
             at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
             at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
             at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
             at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
             at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1119)
             at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:924)
             at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
             at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
             at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
             at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
             at org.broadleafcommerce.common.web.extensibility.MergeContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(MergeContextLoaderListener.java:50)
             at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4210)
             at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4709)
             at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
             at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
             at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:583)
             at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:675)
             at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:601)
             at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:502)
             at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
             at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
             at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
             at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
             at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:822)
             at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
             at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
             at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
             at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
             at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
             at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
             at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
             at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
             at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
             at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
     Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blPersistenceUnitManager' defined in resource loaded from byte array: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateExc$
     [org.broadleafcommerce.common.currency.domain.BroadleafCurrencyImpl, org.broadleafcommerce.common.locale.domain.LocaleImpl, org.broadleafcommerce.common.currency.domain.BroadleafCurrencyImpl]
     are managed classes within the MergePersistenceUnitManager
     but were not detected as being transformed by the EntityMarkerClassTransformer. These
     classes are likely loaded earlier in the application startup lifecyle by the servlet
     container. Verify that an empty <absolute-ordering /> element is contained in your
     web.xml to disable scanning for ServletContainerInitializer classes by your servlet
     container which can trigger early class loading. If the problem persists, ensure that
     there are no bean references to your entity class anywhere else in your Spring applicationContext
     and consult the documentation for your servlet container to determine if classes are loaded
     prior to the Spring context initialization.
             at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
             at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
             at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
             at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
             at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
             at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
             at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
             at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
             ... 40 more
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The classes
     [org.broadleafcommerce.common.currency.domain.BroadleafCurrencyImpl, org.broadleafcommerce.common.locale.domain.LocaleImpl, org.broadleafcommerce.common.currency.domain.BroadleafCurrencyImpl]
     are managed classes within the MergePersistenceUnitManager
     but were not detected as being transformed by the EntityMarkerClassTransformer. These
     classes are likely loaded earlier in the application startup lifecyle by the servlet
     container. Verify that an empty <absolute-ordering /> element is contained in your
     web.xml to disable scanning for ServletContainerInitializer classes by your servlet
     container which can trigger early class loading. If the problem persists, ensure that
     there are no bean references to your entity class anywhere else in your Spring applicationContext
     and consult the documentation for your servlet container to determine if classes are loaded
     prior to the Spring context initialization.
             at org.broadleafcommerce.common.extensibility.jpa.MergePersistenceUnitManager.preparePersistenceUnitInfos(MergePersistenceUnitManager.java:290)
             at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.afterPropertiesSet(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:352)
             at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1573)
             at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1511)
             ... 47 more
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The classes
     [org.broadleafcommerce.common.currency.domain.BroadleafCurrencyImpl, org.broadleafcommerce.common.locale.domain.LocaleImpl, org.broadleafcommerce.common.currency.domain.BroadleafCurrencyImpl]
     are managed classes within the MergePersistenceUnitManager
     but were not detected as being transformed by the EntityMarkerClassTransformer. These
     classes are likely loaded earlier in the application startup lifecyle by the servlet
     container. Verify that an empty <absolute-ordering /> element is contained in your
     web.xml to disable scanning for ServletContainerInitializer classes by your servlet
     container which can trigger early class loading. If the problem persists, ensure that
     there are no bean references to your entity class anywhere else in your Spring applicationContext
     and consult the documentation for your servlet container to determine if classes are loaded
     prior to the Spring context initialization.
             at org.broadleafcommerce.common.extensibility.jpa.MergePersistenceUnitManager.preparePersistenceUnitInfos(MergePersistenceUnitManager.java:286)
             ... 50 more
     [ERROR] 16:09:00 ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
     org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in resource loaded from byte array: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'blPersistenceUnitManager' while setting bean property 'persistenceUnitManager'; nested e$
     [org.broadleafcommerce.common.currency.domain.BroadleafCurrencyImpl, org.broadleafcommerce.common.locale.domain.LocaleImpl, org.broadleafcommerce.common.currency.domain.BroadleafCurrencyImpl]
     are managed classes within the MergePersistenceUnitManager
     but were not detected as being transformed by the EntityMarkerClassTransformer. These
     classes are likely loaded earlier in the application startup lifecyle by the servlet
     container. Verify that an empty <absolute-ordering /> element is contained in your
     web.xml to disable scanning for ServletContainerInitializer classes by your servlet
     container which can trigger early class loading. If the problem persists, ensure that
     there are no bean references to your entity class anywhere else in your Spring applicationContext
     and consult the documentation for your servlet container to determine if classes are loaded
     prior to the Spring context initialization.
             at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:334)
             at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
             at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1419)
             at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
             at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
             at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
             at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
             at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
             at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
             at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
             at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1119)
             at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:924)
             at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
             at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
             at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
             at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
             at org.broadleafcommerce.common.web.extensibility.MergeContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(MergeContextLoaderListener.java:50)
             at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4210)
             at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4709)
             at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
             at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
             at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:583)
             at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:675)
             at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:601)
             at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:502)
             at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
             at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
             at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
             at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
             at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:822)
             at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
             at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
             at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
             at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
             at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
             at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
             at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
             at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
             at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
             at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
     Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blPersistenceUnitManager' defined in resource loaded from byte array: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateExc$
     [org.broadleafcommerce.common.currency.domain.BroadleafCurrencyImpl, org.broadleafcommerce.common.locale.domain.LocaleImpl, org.broadleafcommerce.common.currency.domain.BroadleafCurrencyImpl]
     are managed classes within the MergePersistenceUnitManager
     but were not detected as being transformed by the EntityMarkerClassTransformer. These
     classes are likely loaded earlier in the application startup lifecyle by the servlet
     container. Verify that an empty <absolute-ordering /> element is contained in your
     web.xml to disable scanning for ServletContainerInitializer classes by your servlet
     container which can trigger early class loading. If the problem persists, ensure that
     there are no bean references to your entity class anywhere else in your Spring applicationContext
     and consult the documentation for your servlet container to determine if classes are loaded
     prior to the Spring context initialization.
             at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
             at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
             at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
             at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
             at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
             at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
             at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
             at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
             ... 40 more
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The classes
     [org.broadleafcommerce.common.currency.domain.BroadleafCurrencyImpl, org.broadleafcommerce.common.locale.domain.LocaleImpl, org.broadleafcommerce.common.currency.domain.BroadleafCurrencyImpl]
     are managed classes within the MergePersistenceUnitManager
     but were not detected as being transformed by the EntityMarkerClassTransformer. These
     classes are likely loaded earlier in the application startup lifecyle by the servlet
     container. Verify that an empty <absolute-ordering /> element is contained in your
     web.xml to disable scanning for ServletContainerInitializer classes by your servlet
     container which can trigger early class loading. If the problem persists, ensure that
     there are no bean references to your entity class anywhere else in your Spring applicationContext
     and consult the documentation for your servlet container to determine if classes are loaded
     prior to the Spring context initialization.
             at org.broadleafcommerce.common.extensibility.jpa.MergePersistenceUnitManager.preparePersistenceUnitInfos(MergePersistenceUnitManager.java:290)
             at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.afterPropertiesSet(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:352)
             at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1573)
             at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1511)
             ... 47 more
```

Comment: do you have spring-instrument-tomcat.jar in your tomcat lib folder?

Comment: Yes I do - I have actually rebuilt the server and am now running tomcat 7. I suspect it was something to do with the server.

Comment: so is the issue resolved now?

Comment: Yes - should I delete it?

Comment: well I don't know if you should delete it. But you can try that scenario, if your application runs without that jar you will save some time in server startup.